# How to retrieve a JSONP object from a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonp

I'm trying to make a react component that receives an object and renders multiple divs based on the contents of the object that looks like this:

```
X({
    "data": [
         {"field1": "something", "field2": "something", ...}
         ...
    ]
)}
```

I'm supposed to receive such data from a JSONP request on a server over which I have no control. My approach has been the following:

```
getJSON() {
    let data;

    function X(json) {
        data = JSON.parse(json);
    }

    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://some.path.com/jsonp?callback=X";
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    return data;
}
```

Problem is I get "function X is not defined" in the console when I build the react app. Researching on the web I found out that the function X has to be in the global context to be found by the script when it runs. Is it possible to create a global function from inside a react component? Or if not, what another approach can I try to solve this problem?

Comment: Your function is defined inside the getJSON() function, just define it outside to have it in the global scope

Comment: But if I declare it in the global scope I can't retrieve the data from inside the component. I tried to declare it inside the first react file, the one where you put ReactDOM.render(<Component />, "root"); but it didn't work either.

Comment: who still uses jsonp after cors have been around for years?